# Program that aligns all my folders on the right side of my desktop?

Tags: windows, gratis

Is there a program on Windows 7 ideally that can do this which is to automatically align all my folders on the **right** side of my desktop without manually doing this by using the mouse and dragging them?

Also preferably I want a program that modifies what happens when you save a file on to the desktop and prevents it from being automatically moved to the left side of the desktop.

Features that would be nice to have are....

- Free
- Runs on Windows
- Runs on just one user account (so shouldn't need any administrative rights to run)
- Simple and really basic stuff (E.g. no fancy features, want to keep it basic)

Any suggestions/ideas?

Comment: As a general observation you should try to avoid saving files & folders to your desktop - use short-cuts instead. One of the reasons is that in many corporate or networked environments your desktop is saved to a central server - this is one of the things that slows down shut-down & start-up on a lot of computers when Gigabytes of data need to be transferred due to documents on the desktop.

Comment: You could use the free version of [Fences](http://www.stardock.com/products/fences/) and use the 'first-time auto layout' feature to move folders to specific 'fences', you could move the fence to the right of the screen so all folders are there. ***BUT***, if you want to have the program automatically move programs / icons / folders as you add them, you need the pro version. It is relatively cheap and I've been using it for a year now - works perfect!